# Server2go with newer versions of PHP

Tags: php, server2go

Server2go ( http://www.server2go-web.de/ ) latest downloads have PHP version 5.3.2

Can anyone provide simple instructions for upgrading the PHP element to 5.4.x and 5.5.x

Ideally I would like (for development testing) Server2go with both versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an older question, but I just muddled through the process, so here's what I did to upgrade server2go to PHP 5.4.x:

1. Download a **Thread-Safe** version of PHP that includes the dll php5apache2_2.dll. This file is the only one that will work with Server2Go's Apache version 2.2.15 (Win32). As of the time of writing this, the highest I could upgrade to was PHP 5.4 (5.4.32).

http://windows.php.net/download/

1. In the \server2go\server\ directory, rename the "php" directory "OLD_php".
2. Extract the downloaded ZIP folder into \server2go\server\ and rename it "php".
3. Copy the file libmysql.dll from \server2go\server\OLD_php\ to \server2go\server\php\ to enable the mysql library used by server2go.
4. In the \server2go\server\config_tpl\ directory, make a copy of the php.ini file as a backup and rename it OLD_php.ini, edit the php.ini file and add the following line to the "Dynamic Extensions" section to enable the mysql library used by phpMyAdmin:

**extension=php_mysql.dll**

1. Launch server2go.

If you ever want to run the older version of PHP again, simply rename the files/directories:

- \server2go\server\php\ to \server2go\server\NEW_php\
- \server2go\server\OLD_php\ to **\server2go\server\php\
- \server2go\server\config_tpl\php.ini file to \server2go\server\config_tpl\NEW_php.ini
- \server2go\server\config_tpl\OLD_php.ini to \server2go\server\config_tpl\php.ini

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I'll mark it as my accepted answer as it does answer the question. FYI I have now switched to using UwAmp - www.uwamp.com - similar to server2go, switchable PHP versions, and a great interface.