# PHP Echoing strange characters

Tags: php, html

The program gets 5 variables from 2 database tables and compares them to each other. Each correct match increments a correct variable.

I should be getting a number like "100%" but instead get "�%" and "?%" etc. or just random characters.

See below extract from the HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
<?php

        $user = $_SESSION['currentUser'];

        $answerCheck1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tutorial_exam");
        $answerRowCheck1 = mysqli_fetch_array($answerCheck1);

        $answerCheck2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tutorials_test WHERE user_id='$user'");
        $answerRowCheck2 = mysqli_fetch_array($answerCheck2);

        $answerCheckT = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE user_id='$user'");
        $answerRowCheckT = mysqli_fetch_array($answerCheckT);
        $total = $answerRowCheckT['exam'];
        if($total > 0){$total = $total ."%";}else{$total = '';}

        $counter1 = 1;
        $correct1 = 0;
        $userAnswer1 = '';
        $databaseAnswer1 = '';
        while($counter1 <= 5)
            {
                $index1 = 'q'.$counter1;
                $userAnswer1 = $answerRowCheck2[$index1];
                $databaseAnswer1 = $answerRowCheck1[$index1];
                if($userAnswer1 == $databaseAnswer1)
                {
                    $correct1 = $correct1 + 1;
                    //$correct = $answerRow[$counter];
                }
                $counter1 = $counter1 + 1;
            }
        $mark1 = $correct1 / 5 * 100;
        $mark1 = round($mark1,0);

        echo $mark1 . "%";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd try to drop the percent sign and append it first at the very end...

Comment: Try to set in the header the encode value to `utf-8` or `iso-8859-1` which decode these kind of characters. If you need a fast method to set up the header ,simply add _HTML tags_ `<head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> </head>`, and don't forget to close your html.

Comment: I have tried with both encodings, the browser I use also makes no difference.

Comment: $mark1 is the variable that is displaying incorrectly.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanx for the replies guys, I have tried that and it has not changed anything. See the link to the screenshot below. The strange characters only show on the page in about 1 in every 5 page loads and also only on the first instance of the code that echoes something.

http://postimg.org/image/txizye80p/

Answer (score 0):

We run our system from memory sticks with [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/), and what seems to have fixed it is updating the PHP version on the server2Go systems.

---

We found out how to do that in another Stack Overflow thread: [Other answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481274/server2go-with-newer-versions-of-php)